# Fine numbers - searching

Tags: number-theory

The number of $n$-digit call fine, if for every $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the first $k$ digits creates number divisible by $k$.

How can I search for these numbers?

Comment: It's looks like contest programming problem
For how big n you need to search this number?

Comment: 10^100 this is a range.

Comment: Maybe you post a full  task?
do you want find any this number with 100 digits  or more over?

Comment: I'd expect that the biggest fine number has about 25 digits.

Comment: Joffan, you are right. 
Backtracking generate number with the 25 digits as a number with maximal length

Comment: Do you consider the first digit as the left-most digit or the right-most digit?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the first few are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48.

Answer (score 1):

Simple backtracking works

http://codepad.org/KiKWIkXI  (java)

Only 20456 distinct fine numbers, only one fine number with the 25 digits:

3608528850368400786036725